# Separate row based on the same string in the 1st column in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have cell array containing data as follows :

```
'0'    '2'      '1.000000'    '1.000200'    
'0'    'NaN'    '1.000270'    '1.000570'        
'1'    '3'      '1.000150'    '1.000350'    
'1'    'NaN'    'NaN'         '1.000425'        
'2'    '0'      '1.000225'    '1.000270'
```

I want to separate it to different cell array variable thus as result I will have 3 new cell array variables based on first column value. How to realize this?

Comment: are the elements supposed to be strings or are they numeric types?

Comment: Can you give us an example of the output? I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: @DangKhoa yes it is supposed to be string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply [logical indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/) to cell arrays just as easily as matrices. Use [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) to generate logical arrays based on your cell array.

Let's call your cell array `C`. To get all the rows that contain `'0'` in the first column, you can do:

```
C_has0 = C(cellfun(@(s) s == '0', C(:,1)) , :)
```

The `cellfun` call generates a logical array by checking each element of the first column of `C` to see if it matches `'0'`. In your example, this evaluates to `[true true false false false].'`. Therefore, the above statement becomes

```
C_has0 = C([true true false false false].', :)
```

This statement says "of the 5 rows in `C`, I only want the first two, and get all the columns too".

Rinse and repeat to get `'1'` and `'2'`.

Comment: Thank you it works well. Is it possible to make '0'  and C_has0 here as variable? because later I want to make this runs automatically using for loop so it is like s == 'X' and C_hasX.

Comment: @user2290560 You can easily extend this in a `for` loop. Consider using another cell array whose elements are the cell arrays you generate from above.